# selecting one menu item in a <SelectList> changing the oher <SelectList> value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using  component from material-ui library for multiple options like age,race etc. but the problem is, selecting one menu item in a  changes the value in other  component.

```
      <SelectField
        floatingLabelText="City"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        fullWidth
      >
        <MenuItem value={22} primaryText="New York" />
        <MenuItem value={23} primaryText="London" />
        <MenuItem value={24} primaryText="Paris" />
        <MenuItem value={25} primaryText="Rome" />

     </SelectList>
       <SelectField
        floatingLabelText="Smoker"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        fullWidth
      >
        <MenuItem value={19} primaryText="No" />
        <MenuItem value={20} primaryText="Ex Smoker - Approximate date of 
         quitting" />
        <MenuItem value={21} primaryText="Yes - Approximate consumption per 
        day" />

      </SelectField>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason is**, you are using a single `state` variable to save the value for both `SelectFields`, so if any of the field will change, it will change the other fields also. Instead of one variable, use separate variable for all SelectField.

Define the **separate variable** for these two SelectFields:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {city: null, smoker: null}
}
```

Now use these variables with `SelectField` instead of same:

```
<SelectField
    floatingLabelText="City"
    value={this.state.city}                  //here
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    fullWidth={true}
>
    <MenuItem value={22} primaryText="New York" />
    <MenuItem value={23} primaryText="London" />
    <MenuItem value={24} primaryText="Paris" />
    <MenuItem value={25} primaryText="Rome" />

</SelectList>
<SelectField
    floatingLabelText="Smoker"
    value={this.state.smoker}                //here
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    fullWidth={true}
>
    <MenuItem value={19} primaryText="No" />
    <MenuItem value={20} primaryText="Ex Smoker - Approximate date of quitting" />
    <MenuItem value={21} primaryText="Yes - Approximate consumption per day" />
</SelectField>
```

Comment: thanks. did that. It worked. Initially I changed the value={} to a unique value for each <MenuItem> later I added onChange={(event, index, value)=>{this.setState({ city:value})}}